# Initialize references to matrix element in struct

Tags: c++11, reference, eigen3

I have a struct that represents a 3D position. Sometimes it's convenient to access the individual components and sometimes it's convenient to access all components as a vector (physics vector not std::vector) for which I'm using the Eigen linear algebra library. Since there are only three elements (x, y, z) and will only ever be three elements, is there anything wrong with the struct having three `double&` that refer to the elements of the Eigen Matrix? i.e.:

```
using ColumnVector3 = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>;

struct EnuPosition
{
  EnuPosition(): pos(ColumnVector3::Zero()), east(pos[0]), north(pos[1]), up(pos[2]) {}

  EnuPosition(double east, double north, double up): pos((ColumnVector3() << east, north, up).finished()),
    east(pos[0]), north(pos[1]), up(pos[2]) {}

  EnuPosition(const ColumnVector3& position): pos(position), east(pos[0]), north(pos[1]), up(pos[2]) {}

  EnuPosition(const EnuPosition& enu):pos(enu.pos), east(pos[0]), north(pos[1]), up(pos[2]) {}

  EnuPosition& operator=(const EnuPosition& enu)
  {
    this->pos = enu.pos;
    return *this;  
  }

  ColumnVector3 pos;
  double& east;
  double& north;
  double& up;
};
```

It compiles fine with no warnings on g++ 5.5 with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` in the use cases I can think of:

```
int main ()
{
  EnuPosition enu{12.5, 34.2, 99.2};
  std::cout << "east: " << enu.east
        << " north: " << enu.north 
        << " up: " << enu.up
        << std::endl;

  ColumnVector3 x;
    x << 2.0,3.0,4.0;

  enu.pos = x;

  std::cout << "east: " << enu.east
        << " north: " << enu.north 
        << " up: " << enu.up
        << std::endl;

  Eigen::MatrixXd y;
  y.resize(3,1);

  y << 7.6,8.7,9.8;

  enu.pos = y;

  std::cout << "east: " << enu.east
      << " north: " << enu.north 
      << " up: " << enu.up
      << std::endl;

  Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3> R;

  enu.east = 1;
  enu.north = 1;
  enu.up = 1;

  R << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

  enu.pos = (R * enu.pos).eval();

  std::cout << "east: " << enu.east
    << " north: " << enu.north 
    << " up: " << enu.up
    << std::endl;

  EnuPosition enu2 = enu;
  std::cout << "east: " << enu2.east
    << " north: " << enu2.north 
    << " up: " << enu2.up
    << std::endl;
}
```

Like I said, it works, I'm just curious if it's legal and not relying on undefined behavior, etc. Or are there other issues to be cognizant of?

Comment: I think it is fine. You may also want to implement the copy-assignment `operator=(EnuPosition const &)` (which should only copy `pos`, of course). And you are wasting 24bytes (which is fine, if you only use this type locally).

Comment: @chtz haha yes!  I did more testing and without `operator=` or the copy constructor definitions, the compiler generates default ones that result in the new object references referring to the vector components of the old object. yikes!

Comment: Follow the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))! (For completeness, you may also implement an empty destructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you added the copy-assignment your code should be safe.

However, if you are ok with writing `east()` instead of `east` in your code, then a slightly more elegant solution might be this:

```
using ColumnVector3 = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>;

struct EnuPosition : public ColumnVector3
{
  EnuPosition(): ColumnVector3(ColumnVector3::Zero()) {}

  EnuPosition(double east, double north, double up): ColumnVector3(east, north, up) {}
  template<class X> 
  EnuPosition(const X& other): ColumnVector3(other) {}

  double&       east()        {return this->x();}
  double const& east() const  {return this->x();}
  double&       north()       {return this->y();}
  double const& north() const {return this->y();}
  double&       up()          {return this->z();}
  double const& up() const    {return this->z();}
};
```

If you intentionally don't want to inherit, you can of course still store the `ColumnVector3` as a member.

Comment: what do x, y, and z refer to? Shouldn't it be something like `return (*this)[0]`

Comment: [`.x()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01WriteAccessors_01_4.html#af163a982f5a7ad7e5c3336990b3d7000) does the same as `[0]`. You can use the latter, if you prefer.

Comment: I played around with this solution--I do find having the parentheses after east, etc a little annoying (and was one thing I was actually trying to avoid in the first place), but I think the other advantages of it are pretty compelling.